# How to count the record number per item in SAP crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, formula, line-numbers

I have a set of data in Crystal reports that looks like below:
You can see that each item, they have corresponding quantity.

```
ITEM NAME                QTY         SalesOrder            
Pure Lounge               8          SO18030097 
Spectrum                  1          SO18030098
Cloud                     2          SO18030099
```

However, there are no suppressed details in the report then the line-number should be equal to RecordNumber. So the following formula I got (thanks to this suggestion) is

```
CStr(RecordNumber, "0") & "/" & CStr(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}), "0")
```

and has this  output

```
Pure Lounge                         
1/11                     
SO18030097


Spectrum                        
1/11                     
SO18030098  



Cloud                           
1/11             
SO18030099
```

Notice that it sums all the records which are in total of 11.

But of course, my desired output is

```
Pure Lounge                         
1/8 (up to 8/8)              
SO18030097



Spectrum                        
1/1                  
SO18030098  



Cloud                           
1/2 up to 2/2                
SO18030099
```

Is there something wrong with my formula? Is using RecordNumber formula the correct one? :(

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no suppressed details in the report then the line-number should be equal to `RecordNumber`. So the following formula will show the desired output:

```
CStr(RecordNumber, "0") & "/" & CStr(Count({Table.Column}), "0")
```

Replace `{Table.Column}` with the column that's needed to count the total lines  in your case.

—-

If the report is grouped, then a variable and the grouped itemcount is needed to get the desired output.
Create following formula and put it in the group-header section:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ItemCount := 0;
```

Create another formula and put it in detail section, this will increment the number:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ItemCount := ItemCount + 1;
```

Then, to display the result, use following formula. Replace `GroupedColumn` with the column which is used to group the report:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar ItemNumber;
CStr(ItemNumber, "0") & "/" & CStr(Count({rpt_PackingSlip.LabelQTY}, {rpt_PackingSlip.GroupedColumn}), "0")
```

Comment: but my problem is this formula works if I select only one item to be printed. :( I will update the ticket to provide more screenshots